# C++ Windows return vs ExitProcess

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to create simple program on Windows without any CRT library.

I have two codes:

```
// compile without -lkernel32
int __stdcall _main() {
    return 5;
}
```

and

```
// compile with -lkernel32
#include <windows.h>

void __stdcall _main() {
    ExitProcess(5);
}
```

I am compiling them with MinGW-w64 7.1.0 with this bash script:

```
@echo off
del main.exe 2>nul
C:\Users\Michal\Downloads\mingw64\bin\g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -O3 -s -nostdlib -lkernel32
main.exe
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

The output (exit code) is the same.
(I am using Windows 7 Pro 64-bit)

What code is better? (Maybe better question is: Why does the "return" variant work?)

Edit:

Entrypoint to the program (defaultly pre-set by linker) is _main (normally CRT lib does some work and then calls the 'main' function and calls ExitProcess (or something like that) with value returned from main function).

In my code I am not using CRT library and _main is still the entry-point to the program (and is not calling 'main' function).

Comment: Using the `return` variant is portable code and thus should be preferred.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - this not portable variant, this wrong variant

Comment: You also need to look at exit and _exit.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Many "portable" things rely on the CRT and don't work at all when the standard library is disabled.

Comment: Raymond Chen answered this on his blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100827-00/?p=13023

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not use *CRT*, you need to directly call `ExitProcess`. Without this your process cannot terminate at all. So the variant with only return is wrong.
It will work only if your process has a single thread, otherwise the process will not terminate.

---

You need to understand [How Processes are Terminated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722(v=vs.85).aspx).

A process executes until one of the following events occurs:

- Any thread of the process calls the ExitProcess function
- The last thread of the process terminates
- Any thread calls the TerminateProcess function with a handle to the
  process

When we use *CRT*, it internally calls `ExitProcess`. When we do not use *CRT*, `main` is the true entry point of your exe. After returning, you return directly to kernel32 code. kernel32 code calls `ExitThread` but not `ExitProcess` -- this is very important. So your process will be terminated in this case only if there are no other threads in your process. We can never assume this, however. Beginning with Windows 10, this is usually false. Therefore the only correct way to terminate a process without using *CRT* is to directly call `ExitProcess`.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what is now different with Windows 10?

Comment: @a3f - windows 10 usual automatically create working threads in any process for load dlls in "parallel" - this is so called parallel loader. as result always several threads in your app. simply call `ExitThread` is already not enough. however this working threads exited after 30 seconds of idle - process in this case can terminate after 30 second

Answer (score 9):

You are correct that why the `return` version works is key to understanding which is better.

The important thing here is that `main` is not the entrypoint for a Windows console application.  The entrypoint is in library code, which initializes memory, calls constructors on global variables, splits the command line into `argc`/`argv` format, and then calls `main` saving the return value.

If `main` does return, it returns to the library code which calls `atexit`-registered functions and destructors for static variables, then calls `ExitProcess`.

Therefore there's really only one way to set the exit value, by calling `ExitProcess`.  But doing it yourself will skip the cleanup actions taken by the library -- if you call `ExitProcess` then destructors don't get called and you might end up with loss of data stuck in write buffers.

When you build without the standard library, then library actions of construction/destruction aren't relevant, and calling `ExitProcess` explicitly is nearly the same as returning.  There still is a library-provided call frame which catches your return value and calls `ExitThread` if you don't, but it comes from the OS itself (kernel32.dll) when there is no CRT.  As RmMb points out, this is an important difference, because other threads won't be killed; the process will exit if all threads exit.

Comment: `without any CRT library.` - so in this case `main` is true entrypoint of exe

Comment: @RbMm: The user entrypoint isn't the first frame on the stack though, there's still an OS entrypoint in kernel32, right?  `main` is the "true" entrypoint insofar as its address is listed in the PE header, but execution still doesn't start there.

Comment: yes, not first instruction in user mode. but kernel32 entry point not call `ExitProcess` - it call `ExitThread`

Comment: so return - is wrong and not works. never works in win 10

Comment: @RbMm: Well, it works to call `ExitThread`... if you wanted `ExitProcess` then it is wrong.

Comment: @RbMb: I mean that returning from the user entrypoint is guaranteed to call `ExitThread`.  Not that `ExitThread` is guaranteed to exit the process.